# Python identity operators

Tags: python

Please clarify my doubt about python identity operators is and is not.

```
a,b = 10.0, 10.0
print (a is b)
```

will result in True

where as

```
a = 10.0
b = 10.0
print (a is b)
```

will result in False

Why in the first case the id() function results is same value and different in the second case

Comment: In both cases it prints true

Comment: Because unimportant implementation details. It doesn't matter. Python doesn't promise what either of these comparisons will return.

Comment: I can reproduce OPs behaviour using python 3.6. Using python 2.7 both are `False`.

Comment: I got both True using Python 3.6

Comment: @Mufeed: You probably ran the snippets as scripts instead of interactively. The behavior is different because more unimportant implementation details.

Comment: Yes. I ran as script.

Comment: Can you explain in detail why it happens? @user2357112

Comment: That's a little dismissive, @user2357112  – the OP is obviously interested in why this happens and if you find it too unimportant to bother with, you can just move on.

Comment: @xnx But the Python language basically explicitly defines that both `True` and `False` are possible here, so any code that relies n either is incorrect. There are interesting questions here, but they're (a) specific to a particular implementation, and (b) lower level than this. For example, in this case, the reason the first one is true is an artifact of CPython's compiler constant folding (which isn't true for, say, Jython), and the reason the second is false is that each statement is a separate compilation unit (which isn't true if you put the exact same code in a module or script).

Comment: @abarnert That's pretty much the basis of a decent answer to the question, which I think is a reasonable one for anyone curious about better understanding the language to ask. In any case the duplicate assigned to it provides plenty to go on.

Comment: @abarnert thanks for the clarifications.